# Uniqueness of linear maps proof

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $u_1,u_2,u_3$ be a basis of $\mathbb{C}^3$ and let $v_1,v_2,v_3$ be any three vectors in $\mathbb{C}^3$. Prove that there is a unique linear map $T: \mathbb{C^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{C^3}$ with $T(u_i) = v_i$ for all $i \in \{1,2,3\}$

I have no idea how to prove uniqueness or the existence here really. Not sure of any strategies I could use, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Define** $\;T:\Bbb C^3\to\Bbb C^3\;$ by precisely $\;Tu_k:=v_k\;$ , and now, since *any* $\;x\in\Bbb C^3\;$ has **a unique** expressions as $\;x=\sum_{k=1}^3 a_ku_k\;,\;\;a_k\in\Bbb C\;$ , simply extend the definition

$$Tx:=\sum_{k=1}^3 a_kv_k$$

Now prove this $\;T\;$ fulfills everything that must be fulfilled (very easy)

Comment: Ok, but what exactly does this map do? Map $u_1$ to $v_1$, $u_2$ to $v_2$, etc.?

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove Yes, of course...but **also** it maps *any* $\;x\in\Bbb C^3\;$ as shown, and it is linear, does what it is supposed to do...and it is *unique*